# sql not returning rows as expected

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-xi

What I am trying to do is this.
table OEINHDIH is history of orders. Orders can have many order type rows. so that order 12345 can have types INT, COR etc within it.
we need the orders which are INT but don't have a correction order against it (COR COE). But when i run this sql i get only 1 ihent#. Also this has to be run in Crystal report where the user will drive this according to dates from and to which is h.IHDOCD.

```
select h.IHDOCD, h.IHENT#, h.IHSFX#, h.IHINV#, a.ADINTA                   
from astdta.OEINHDIH  h                                                   
  join astdta.Adressad a                                                  
    on h.ihent# = a.ADENT#                                                
where h.IHORDT = 'INT'                                                    
  AND h.IHVIAC not in ('PML','FCM')                                       
  AND ADSFX# = '000'                                                      
  and h.ihent# in (                                                       
    select cor.ihent#                                                     
      from astdta.OEINHDIH cor                                            
      where cor.IHORDT not in ('COR','COE'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

I do believe your table `astdta.OEINHDIH` can contain data like :

```
ihen# | IHORDT 
   1  | 'INT' 
   1  | 'COR'
   2  | 'INT'
   3  | 'INT'
   3  | 'COE'
```

In terms of performance, you should use `left join` + content `is null` instead of `subquery` to exclude corrected orders

```
select h.IHDOCD, h.IHENT#, h.IHSFX#, h.IHINV#, a.ADINTA                   
from astdta.OEINHDIH  h 
    left join astdta.OEINHDIH cor -- get orders corrected
        on h.ihent# = cor.ihent#   
        and cor.IHORDT in ('COR','COE')            
    join astdta.Adressad a                                                  
        on h.ihent# = a.ADENT#                                                
where h.IHORDT = 'INT' 
    and cor.ihent# is null -- remove orders corrected                                  
    AND h.IHVIAC not in ('PML','FCM')                                       
    AND ADSFX# = '000'
```

If you are missing rows that means you `join` or your `where` are excluding to much row

1. Is `h.ihent# = a.ADENT#` correct ?
2. Is `h.IHVIAC not in ('PML','FCM')` correct ?
3. Is `ADSFX# = '000'` correct ?

If you need to check that h.IHDOCD is between date use :

```
    AND h.IHDOCD BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

with start_date and end_date formatted to the correct type.

I have some lack of information, so if I'm missing something, give me more informations on :

- What you need
- What are your data tables
- What are your tables structure
- What is your expected result